# Wordpress Featured Image with Overlay Color based on Category

Tags: wordpress

i'm looking for a plugin that does the following:

I want that each featured image of each post has a semi transparent overlay over the image by default (not on hovering).

(nothing complex up to now, but here is the challenge)

However, I want that transparent overlay to have a specific color depending on the post category.

And so, I could set a color overlay for each category.

Comment: Hi this does not sound so hard, should be relatively easy to setup, do you have Advanced custom fields or similar installed on your site?

Comment: Yes, I do have custom fields enable

Comment: In that case you could add a custom colour picker to your categories then call the result for each post in that category for the overlay.